# Rodar o adb em vários containers docker

Tags: android, docker

Eu tenho quatro telefones conectados via USB. Tenho dois `containers docker` rodando na minha máquina e cada um deles tem um `adb` rodando. 
Os adbs selecionam os celulares aleatoriamente, eu gostaria de mapear dois celulares para um docker e dois celulares para o outro.

Todos os aparelhos estão sendo listados em `/dev/ttyACM3/`

Existe uma forma de mapear o aparelho para um docker específico? Ou o contrário, fazer o docker reconhecer apenas determinados aparelhos?

O que tentei até agora foi montar o aparelho individualmente, se eu montar o `/dev/ttyACM3/001` por exemplo, em um container, o adb reconhece, mas quando é reconectado o arquivo pode mudar de 001 para 002, ou 003, ou 004, depende de como o sistema operacional monta os aparelhos, ou em que ordem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma regra `udev` com o nome baseado no `código serial` da porta usb, e passar esse código para o docker.